# Multi line string trim

Tags: tcl

I have a problem string which has multiple lines:

```
line1 
Link1: //website/go/<example> 
line2
```

I am trying to make trim to get just web page link part (*just address which can be various - in this case "//website/go/"*) but there are some extra signs before and after.

My try:

```
set temp [string map { " " "" "line1" "" "Link1: " "" "line2" "" } $output]
puts "found link : $temp
```

And the output of it is:

```
found link :<empty line>
//website/go/<example>
<empty line>`
```

How can I remove all white spaces, newlines, etc. and trim it in way to get just the part of the string which I am looking for. In this case to get just: `//website/go/<example>`?

Comment: Will the URL always be the 2nd word of the 2nd line?

Comment: [Please post your attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes it will always be second line.

Comment: post is updated by "my try"

Comment: Please update with expected results

Comment: Updated with expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this input data:

```
line1 
Link1: //website/go/<example> 
line2
```

You can use `string map` as you do and then post-process the result with `string trim` (assuming you only expect one thing left at the end) *or* remove the newlines with another mapping element. On two lines for clarity:

```
set temp [string map { " " "" "line1" "" "Link1: " "" "line2" "" } $output]
set temp [string trim $temp]
puts "found link : $temp
```

However, in this case I'd *actually* use `regexp` to pick the data I want:

```
regexp -line {Link1:\s+(.*\S)} $output -> temp
puts "found link : $temp
```

Regular expressions tend to be more suitable for parsing part-formatted data, provided you remember to keep them short. The longer a RE is, the harder it is to understand.